# dispatcher.invoke on mainwindow from another object in a backgroundworker

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, backgroundworker

I created an object (obj1) and also a BackgroundWorker (bgw1) in a main window (win form).

In the eventhandler of the `bgw1.DoWork` event, I let it call a method of obj1 (`obj1.method1()`). 
In his method (`obj1.method1()`) I create another object (obj2) and also another thread (th1).
I let it run methods of obj2 in this thread (th1).

Note that, th1 never ends.

Obj2 in the th1 creates data. I need to get this data on the main window, right there when the data is created..

When I use a normal event to deliver this data to a method of main window, I receive errors, because of unsafe thread communication.
So I need to use Dispatcher.
But it is not possible to call a method of main window from obj2.

How should be the usage of Dispatcher be here, if it is possible to use it in this case? 
Or what should be the solution, any idea?
How about using interface? if possible, how?

To make the question more simple, code is here, like:

```
class main
{
  functMain()
  {
    // code..
  }

  obj1 = new Obj(); 

  Thread th = new Thread(obj);
  th.Start();
}


class Obj
{
  event EventHandler<param1> eDataReceived;

  func()
  {
   //invoke eDataReceived event here and pass a parameter to functMain
  }
}
```

Comment: It would help if you edited your question to include the relevant parts of the code.

Comment: Dispatcher is a WPF concept, not a winforms one. You need to use Invoke/BeginInvoke on the form.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've edited your question a bit; I hope it will now be more clear to visitors. You can further [edit] it, it might help if you provided a small sample of the code, to illustrate the problem. Stack Overflow users "markdown" for editing. To get something in `code markdown`, indent it by 4 spaces. To put a sentence in a new line, add two spaces at the end. Good luck!

Comment: Updating Winforms controls from another threads can cause deadlocks, so even there exists some workarounds (using Invoke methods) it is not advisable. Instead can you tell us what you doing on another threads? - if you loading data from  some external resources - you can use `async-await` for doing it effectively on one thread and update controls. If you doing some calculations then you can consider to return calculated result and update controls on UI thread. Notice that `BackgroundWorker` have `ProgressChanged` and `RunWorkerCompleted` which executes on UI thread.